# Factorial factor when finding odd/ even part of a tensor

Tags: tensors

Suppose we want antisymmetric part of product of component of three vector, we have:

$$ \zeta^{[r} \eta^s \chi^{t]} = \frac16 (\zeta^r \eta^s \chi^t + \zeta^t \eta^r \chi^s - \zeta^r \eta^t \chi^s - \zeta^t \eta^s \chi^r - \zeta^s \eta^r \chi^t) $$

Now I am confused as to why this $\frac16$ factor came. I think it should just be $\frac{1}{3}$ because if we see the possible of odd permtuation in $S_{3}$, that is just $\frac{3!}{2} =3$. However everywhere I look it's $3!$, could someone explain?

Comment: Suppose you have a tensor $T^{rst}$. You know that the antisymmetric part of $T$ has to be $$A^{rst} =  a(T^{rst} + T^{str} + T^{trs} - T^{rts} - T^{tsr} - T^{srt}) $$ for some constant $a$. If $T$ is antisymmetric, then all 6 terms in the formula for $A$ are equal and therefore $A^{rst} = 6aT^{rst}$. On the other hand, if $T$ is antisymmetric, then you want $A = T$. Therefore, $$a = \frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: Damn why did I never read this anywhere else. You should post that as answer. Thought it was crazy insightful @Deane

Comment: So actually the odd permutation terms are not all those which make up the odd terms.