# Factorial term when evaluating the exterior derivative through the connection definition

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, connections

I found perhaps a hint of what the relation is on page-316 of Penrose's Road to reality. For $ p- $ form $\alpha$ with index epxression, $\alpha_{b...d}$ , and a torsion free connection $\nabla_a$

$$(d \alpha)_{ab..d} = \text{anti symm}(\nabla_{a} \alpha_{b...d })$$

I compute the derivative of a two form using the above exp:

$$ \alpha = \alpha_{23} dx^2 \wedge dx^3+ \alpha_{31} dx^3 \wedge dx^1 + \alpha_{12} dx^1 \wedge dx^2$$

We must now write this in the tensor notation, by using the definition of wedge product in terms of tensor products. We have:

$$ \alpha = \alpha_{23} dx^2 \otimes dx^3 - \alpha_{23} dx^3 \otimes dx^2 + ... \text{stuff}$$

By the above, we can identify $\alpha$ in component form as $\alpha_{ij}$ with $\alpha_{ij} = - \alpha_{ji}$, we now Penrose's definition:

$$ (d \alpha)_{aij} = \text{anti symm} ( \nabla_a \alpha_{ij})=  \frac13 \left[  \nabla_a \alpha_{ij}  + \nabla_j \alpha_{ai} - \nabla_{i} \alpha_{aj} \right]=$$

$$ \frac13\left[  \nabla_a \alpha_{ij}  + \nabla_j \alpha_{ai} - \nabla_{i} \alpha_{aj} \right] = \frac13 \left[ \frac{\partial \alpha_{ij} }{\partial x^a} -\Gamma_{ai}^p \alpha_{pj} - \Gamma_{aj}^p \alpha_{pi} + \frac{\partial \alpha_{ai} }{\partial x^j}  -\Gamma_{ja}^p \alpha_{pi} - \Gamma_{ji}^p \alpha_{ap}- \frac{\partial \alpha_{aj}}{\partial x^i} + \Gamma_{ia}^p \alpha_{pj} +\Gamma_{ij}^p \alpha_{ap} \right]$$

Now due to the very convenient choice of our connection (torsion free), all the Christoffels are symmetric in lower indices and all cancel out:

$$ \left[ \nabla_a \alpha_{ij} + \nabla_j \alpha_{ai} - \nabla_i \alpha_{aj} \right] = \frac{\partial \alpha_{ij} }{\partial x^a} + \frac{\partial \alpha_{ai}}{\partial x^j } - \frac{\partial \alpha_{aj} }{\partial x^i }= \frac{\partial \alpha_{ij} }{\partial x^a} + \frac{\partial \alpha_{ai}}{\partial x^j } +\frac{\partial \alpha_{ja} }{\partial x^i }$$

Now since the differential form is a totally anti symmetric tensor evaluating at only one of the permutation determine value at all other permutation. In case of repeating indices, it is is trivially zero. So, let us evaluate at 1,2,3:

$$ (d \alpha)_{123}= \frac13 \left[ \frac{\partial \alpha_{23}}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial \alpha_{31}}{\partial x_2} + \frac{ \partial \alpha_{12}}{\partial x_3}\right]$$

This entry can be used to directly write down the expression in terms of the wedge product:

$$ d \alpha = \frac13 (\frac{\partial \alpha_{23}}{\partial x_1} + \frac{\partial \alpha_{31}}{\partial x_2} + \frac{ \partial \alpha_{12}}{\partial x_3}) dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge dx_3$$

Seems so that I am off by a factor of $\frac13$.. where is the mistake? I've been trying to figure out what went wrong for about three days with no progress :(.

Btw for the antisymmetric part, I use the expression in comments by Deane in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4456520/688539) and combined the last three terms by first three using the pre-existing antisymmetric of lost two slots of the differential form.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a factor of $1/2$ in the antisymmetrization? Many authors define the antisymmetrization as: $dx\wedge dy=\frac{1}{2}(dx\otimes dy-dy\otimes dx)$. It could be that Penrose is using a similar convention. Also, you probably have to take permutations over all indices when computing $\nabla_{[a}\alpha_{ij]}$, and you have $3!$ such objects, some of them will simplify using that $\alpha$ is antisymmetric.

Comment: Since it is a differential form already and anti symm in last two indice, some of those 3! term merged to give me only three terms @JohnnyLemmon . Maybe it is matter of definition I'll check it out.